# anaconda python installation messed up and unable to install ijavascript

Tags: python, anaconda, ijavascript

I've been using anaconda python for over an year without any troubles in multiple systems, I wanted to start coding with javascript. So I wanted to install a javascript kernel in jupyter. Because I'm addicted to jupyter and can't seem to program anywhere else. I was getting the `configure error` when I tried `npm install -g ijavascript`. After some research I decided to reinstall anaconda; I've now removed and reinstalled anaconda multiple times. In one of those instances I installed it for "All Users" on my windows 10; which is why I think python environment path got screwed up, but I switched it back to current user with a reinstall. I tried to set the python environment variable in windows `advanced system settings` but it still doesn't work in command line. 
I figured I should try `npm install -g ijavascript` from the anaconda prompt instead, since it recognizes `python` command. But I get the exact same error that I got through command line. Screenshot Below -

When I research manually setting the python path, the answers apply to earlier anaconda installations (I think) , because they don't point to the same directories.

Can I get some guidance in setting python environment variable for the latest anaconda, and then install `ijavascript`.

**UPDATE:** My work computer has everything normally setup. Can access python through windows command prompt. But I'm getting the exact same error below on this computer as well. Also, The anaconda installation on this PC is default and never tampered with.

[image]

Comment: Tried on my work computer with exact same error

Comment: Last year, ijavascript kernel on my windows screwed up. I decided to start using WSL and install Jupyter notebook/lab on it. Now I have all the kernels that run smoothly:-  octave + nodeJS(ijavascript) + R and a couple of python kernels. Let them run on Linux (WSL) and open browsers on Windows to use them is recommended for your next move.